# 2 Woocommerce Installations with same products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I dont know if this is possible but I would like to create my Woocommerce Shop Frace65.com into multilingual. But the Plugins to make this happen are to expensive for me. Is it possible to install a new Wordpress but connect the Woocommerce products, sales etc from both installations togheter in one database?

Comment: There are free plugins for this: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Comment: @David.J unfortunately its not free its 99$ https://polylang.pro/downloads/polylang-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this free plugin which is compatible with WooCommerce - [WP Multilang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang/). No need of any add-ons and its tab-based language switching in admin panel would be very user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible to install wordpress and woocommerce in one database. You can just follow the steps by link, https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/start-with-woocommerce-in-5-steps/

Comment: Thanks for the Ansewer. So I can create the same Wordpress Site but in German and when someone buys something on the german shop, it will also be makred as sold on the other store?

Answer (score 0):

Use [qTranslate-X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) with the Woocommerce addon. Yes, the plugin is a little old now, but there is [a project to revive it](https://github.com/qtranslate/qtranslate-xt) and bring it up to date. That said, I use it on 2 sites, one with Woocommerce, and can confirm that it works perfectly well. It's free and has the major advantage that all of the translations are kept in the same post, so there's no duplication.